# komascript - typearea bug

Tags: luatex, koma-script, typearea

So I have this letter template, which used to work fine until recently. I know there was a bug in the komascript classes <3.21. My distro maintainer (Arch Linux) has upgraded komascript to 3.21.
Here is my MWE:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage[english=british]{csquotes}


\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[scale=0.775]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\addtolength{\parskip}{6pt}

\def\firstname{John}
\def\familyname{Doe}
\def\FileAuthor{\firstname \familyname}
\def\FileTitle{\firstname \familyname's }
\def\FileSubject{Letter}
\def\FileKeyWords{\firstname \familyname, Letter}

\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}

\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{tt}
\ifpdf
  \usepackage[pdftex,pdfborder=0,breaklinks,baseurl=http://,pdfpagemode=None,pdfstartview=XYZ,pdfstartpage=1]{hyperref}
  \hypersetup{
    pdfauthor   = \FileAuthor,%
    pdftitle    = \FileTitle,%
    pdfsubject  = \FileSubject,%
    pdfkeywords = \FileKeyWords,%
    pdfcreator  = \LaTeX,%
    pdfproducer = \LaTeX}
\else
  \usepackage[dvips]{hyperref}
\fi


\begin{document}
\sffamily   % for use with a résumé using sans serif fonts;
%\rmfamily  % for use with a résumé using serif fonts;
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.6\textwidth}
\raggedleft%
{\bfseries John doe}\\[.35ex]
\small\itshape%
Field Lane\\
 Austria\\[.35ex]
\Telefon~+43~730~1234756\\
\Letter~\href{mailto:john@doe.com}{john@doe.com}
\end{minipage}\\[1em]
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}
\raggedright%
{\bfseries T-Mobile}\\[.35ex]
\small\itshape%
Cross Lane\\
Vienna
\end{minipage}
\hfill % US style
%\\[1em] % UK style
\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}
\raggedleft % US style
\today
%April 6, 2006 % US informal style
%05/04/2006 % UK formal style
\end{minipage}\\[2em]
\raggedright
Dear Sir or Madam,\\[1.5em]



%Yours sincerely,\\[2em] % if the opening is "Dear Mr(s) Doe,"
Yours faithfully,\\[2em] % if the opening is "Dear Sir or Madam,"
%
{\bfseries John doe}\\
%
\vfill%
%{\slshape Enclosure}
{\slshape Attachment:{Invoice}}
\end{document}
```

Here is the associated part of the error log:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\PDF@SetupDoc ...pstringB {\@baseurl }\pdfcatalog 
                                                  {/PageMode/\@pdfpagemode \...
l.44 \begin{document}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\PDF@SetupDoc ... \@pdfnumcopies \fi }\pdfcatalog 
                                                  {\ifx \Hy@temp \@empty \el...
l.44 \begin{document}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\Hy@DestName #1#2->\pdfdest 
                            name{#1}#2\relax 
l.44 \begin{document}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
\relax 
l.44 \begin{document}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
\relax 
l.44 \begin{document}

Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \pdfpageheight 

l.44 \begin{document}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
\relax 
l.44 \begin{document}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
\relax 
l.44 \begin{document}
```

Is this error still caused by komascript or some other package?
If I insert `\usepackage{luatex85}` it does compile, so I am wondering if this is another komascript related?!

Comment: This has nothing to do with KOMA (directly) but with changes in the `luatex` engine which do not preserve backwards compatibility. This is why loading the `luatex85` package solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! 
Do you have any idea to make the 'offending' code part compatible to the updated luatex engine? Or shall I just go the easy way and add this package to my old files?

Comment: I think that adding the package is the simplest solution.